# ui:decorate supersedes ui:composition and ui:include?

Tags: templates, jsf-2, facelets

this is a summary of what i understood:

`ui:decorate`

1. can use `ui:define`
2. can use `ui:param`
3. can have external content

`ui:composition`

1. can use `ui:define`
2. can use `ui:param`
3. -> can NOT have external content

`ui:include`

1. -> can NOT use `ui:define`
2. can use `ui:param`
3. can have external content

assumed these, i can use

`ui:decorate` as `ui:composition`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <!-- no content here -->

    <ui:decorate template="templates/page.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="test">
            <h:outputText value="#{someBean.someProperty}"/>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:decorate>

    <!-- no content here -->
</html>
```

`ui:decorate` as `ui:include`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:panelGroup>...</h:panelGroup>

    <ui:decorate template="fragments/page.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="test" value="#{someBean.someProperty}"/>
    </ui:decorate>

    <h:panelGroup>...</h:panelGroup>
</html>
```

so, am i missing something? misunderstanding?

if i'm right, why are there 3 different components? (please do not say that they are used for different goals, if i'm right)